# The font of my modelsim is too small to see

Tags: linux, fedora, modelsim

[image: Modelsim screenshot]

As you can see, the font of modelsim's text editor is very small. But I can't change the size in *Tools->Edit Preferences->Source Window->Fonts*.
However, I can make the letters bigger by set the DPI higher(through *System Settings->Fonts*) or set the resolution of the screen to a appropriate value, such as 1024X720, while 1366x768 is the actual resolution of my screen. These ways are not comfortable, because everything else look strange.My **OS is Fedora 22**, and the version of my **Modelsim is 10.3d**.

I want to get a more comfortable way to the font-size problem of Modelsim, I'll appreciate it!

Comment: I'm on windows, but the *Tools->Edit Preferences->Source Window->Fonts->textFont* seems to work for me. At first I thought it was the *fixedFont*, but this does not apply to the source window.

Comment: yeah,you are right.But things are different on Fedora 22(KDE). no matter what I changed in Fonts(fixedFont or textFonts), the font-size just stay tiny, except I change the resolution or DPI of my computer.

Comment: Sounds like a ModelSim bug. Since you're using the free Altera version, I'm not sure if you'll be able to get any support. If you have a Mentor SupportNet login, you may be able to create a support request.

Comment: It only happens on KDE. Maybe clear some environment variables to make ModelSim think it is not running on KDE?

Answer (score 21):

I ran into this too in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with modelsim 10.5 ASE. I fixed it as follows:

1. Open ~/.modelsim (use "nano ~/.modelsim" in terminal)
2. Find: PrefDefault = ... textFontV2 {Verdana 12} (the name of the font may differ)
3. Change 12 to -12, so it will looks like this: textFontV2 {Verdana -12}
4. Save ~/.modelsim (Ctrl+O and then Enter)
5. Reopen modelsim

Comment: Works here on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Kind-of works for me on Ubuntu 17.10: Now the fonts in the source and interestingly also in the transcript window are a bit too large though. Changing the -12 to -10 or even -8 doesn’t seem to make any difference though. Any ideas?

Comment: Works for 18.04. Thanks.

Comment: Changing the font from 12 to -12 led to the error mentioned in https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/455792/how-to-come-out-of-the-transcript-window-of-modelsim-which-is-stuck . Changing it back to 12 in ~/.modelsim resolved that issue.

Comment: my changes in ~/.modelsim reset when I reopen modelsim

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this too in Xubuntu, just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to enlarge or shrink the text dynamically.

Comment: This works for me, but only with the Numpad +/- keys. Howerver, it makes the "Ln#" column on the left huuuge.

Answer (score 6):

Tools->Edit preferences->source windows-> textFont

Answer (score 1):

I am using CentOS Linux, `Questa Sim-64 10.1a` and had the same problem. I fixed it as follows :

1. Select "Tools" option from the toolbar at the top.
2. From the drop down menu select "Edit Preferences ..."
3. On the lower left pane, there are various Font types like fixedFont, footerFont, textFont etc. To change the size of textFont, select it and you get the choice of font type and size.
4. Choose what you are most comfortable with.
5. menuFont is used for command prompt and treeFont is used to display the folder structure.

Answer (score 1):

**On Xubuntu/XFCE4:** Going to Settings⟶Appereance⟶Fonts and disabling the *"Custom DPI setting"* checkbox solved the problem for me.

[image: XFCE4 Font Settings]

The strange thing is that `xdpyinfo` says the screen resolution is 96x96 dpi regardless of the checkbox. Leaving the checkbox on and setting something like 200 dpi scales the Modelsim editor font, but also all other fonts on the screen, so that doesn't help. I didn't dig any further towards the root cause.

Comment: Works for me on Xubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

[I apologize for my previous response.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/piUcL.png)

Here is my revised answer.

---

I'll provide the answer directly with a screenshot.This is more intuitive.

1. click [`Tools->Edit Preferences`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pKnLz.png)
2. click [`By Name->Find`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ac0AY.png)

After clicking the "Find" button, a window named "Find in Preferences" will pop up. [This is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIeyP.png)

3. Enter "font" in the "Find" input box
4. Continue clicking the `Find Next` button until the value of the "Preference Item" becomes "textFontV2." [This is the screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6RQt.png)
5. Click `Change Value` button and set the value for "textFontV2" to `monospace -12 normal roman`. [This is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udIRg.png)
6. Click `OK` button of "Change Value" window and close "Change Value" window.
7. Click `Apply` button of Preferences window.
   **After clicking `Apply`, do not click `OK`. Close the window directly.**